# How to get uitableViewCell for specific row in specific section swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

How would you get the UITableViewCell for a specific row in a specific section of a tableView in swift?

Comment: What do you hope to get from a cell that you can't get from your data source?

Comment: I don't know if it's different in swift, but (ObjC) `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should already be implemented by the OP to provide exactly that, right? (regardless of 'visibility').

Answer (score 0):

[`func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:), but it only returns a cell if the cell is visible.